# Call NTLMv2 secured endpoint via Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, httpclient, ntlm, ntlmv2

I am using Apache Camel 2.19 and I am able to use NTLMv1 when calling my endpoint using camel-http module that supports NTLMv1 out of the box:

```
from("activemq:{{queue.feedback}}")
    .to("http://localhost:8888/ntlm/secured?authMethodPriority=NTLM 
                 &authMethod=NTLM&authUsername=Zaphod
                 &authPassword=Beeblebrox&authDomain=Minor
                 &authHost=LightCity")
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to make a request using NTLMv2.
The [official documentation](http://camel.apache.org/http.html) states that:

> Note: camel-http is based on HttpClient v3.x and as such has only
>   limited support for what is known as NTLMv1, the early version of the
>   NTLM protocol. It does not support NTLMv2 at all. camel-http4 has
>   support for NTLMv2.

When I try to use camel-http4 it does just nothing:

```
from("activemq:{{queue.feedback}}")
    .to("http4://localhost:8888/ntlm/secured?authMethodPriority=NTLM 
                 &authMethod=NTLM&authUsername=Zaphod
                 &authPassword=Beeblebrox&authDomain=Minor
                 &authHost=LightCity")
```

It seems that camel-http4 is not aware of NTLM at all. I tried to investigate camel-http4 [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/camel-2.19.x/components/camel-http4) and I couldn't find anything related to NTLM besides the documentation.

**Any ideas of how can I use NTLMv2 in Camel 2.19 (other versions of Camel may be a good fit as well)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in camel-http4 component. By default, it uses **InputStreamEntity which is not a repeatable implementation of HttpEntity entity** meaning that once you read a stream - it's closed and you can't read it again. This causes a failure in MainClientExec:

```
if (execCount > 1 && !RequestEntityProxy.isRepeatable(request)) {
    throw new NonRepeatableRequestException("Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity.");
}
```

This seems to be a bug, therefore the workaround is to convert  InputStreamEntity to the ByteArrayEntity (which is repeatable) just before sending the request:

```
@Component
public class NtlmProcessor implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        HttpEntity httpEntity = exchange.getIn().getBody(HttpEntity.class);

        byte[] bytes = EntityUtils.toByteArray(httpEntity);

        ByteArrayEntity byteArrayEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(bytes, ContentType.get(httpEntity));

        exchange.getOut().setBody(byteArrayEntity);
    }
}
```